# Twitter like notification when new posts are made

Tags: views, notifications, social-network

I was wondering if there was a module out there that could replicate something to what Twitter do when you have new Tweets you haven't seen in your timeline (so a notification of how many new items there are without refreshing the page).

See examples of what I mean, not the best at explaining things. preferably without using node.js as it hasn't worked for me so far!

Thanks in advance

[image: Twitter exmaple]

[image: Tab notification]

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodeJS to push live updates to your website without refreshing it, thus you also can count the new items.

There is a module that integrates with nodeJS: https://www.drupal.org/project/nodejs

You will need SSH access to make this work I think.

Comment: Thanks Robin will try this out when I get home this evening, know of any good tutorials for using this?

Comment: http://nodeschool.io/ is a good website for nodeJS tutorials

Comment: I had a play around with it yesterday but to no avail - any pointers of where to start, or alternatives?

Comment: Did you get nodeJS running? I used it before and I'm a 100% positive that your use case is something for nodeJS

Comment: Yup got it working and setup a rule - followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWD2iQB0zdg but still no luck.